# Authenticate Linux<->LDAP Protocol<->AD(active directory): Fail to logon with password

Tags: authentication, pam, ldap, active-directory, nsswitch

I spent much time on this and even successfully verified (Auth)Linux-LDAP-openLDAP ok. But get blocked with AD. 
I can now switch to user from root account but can not log on with password (**pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure**). I will see if I can turn on pam debug and also raise the problem here. 
I want to list the detailed steps here to get helps. 
I am not sure it is related to userPassword
(I already set  dsHeuristics to 000000001) or unixUserPassword attribute,
but I will continue to investigate.

1. Windows Server 2012 R2 (AD) side: Setup AD DS. Enable SSL for AD. Installed [Identity Management for UNIX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731178(v=ws.11)#BKMK_command)
   Add attributes(uidNumber,gidNumber,unixHomeDirectory) to global catalog in [schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc755885(v=ws.10)). 
   Added couple of users (luser02 which is the bind user, luser03, luser04) and group (unixGrp2) with posixAccount/posixGroup set, respectively. 
   To verify it, I can use `ldapsearch` in the target CentOS 6:

   `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://114.116.43.118:389 -D "CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com" -b "DC=kelamayi,DC=com" -W sAMAccountName=luser03`

   ```
   # extended LDIF
   #
   # LDAPv3
   # base <DC=kelamayi,DC=com> with scope subtree
   # filter: sAMAccountName=luser03
   # requesting: ALL
   #

   # luser03, Users, kelamayi.com
   dn: CN=luser03,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: posixAccount
   objectClass: person
   objectClass: organizationalPerson
   objectClass: user
   cn: luser03
   givenName: luser03
   distinguishedName: CN=luser03,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   instanceType: 4
   whenCreated: 20180824095929.0Z
   whenChanged: 20180824103333.0Z
   displayName: luser03
   uSNCreated: 24826
   memberOf: CN=unigGrp2,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   memberOf: CN=unixGrp,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   uSNChanged: 24861
   name: luser03
   objectGUID:: Q/Bx5j48CEWikaDPlHoyRw==
   userAccountControl: 66048
   badPwdCount: 0
   codePage: 0
   countryCode: 0
   badPasswordTime: 0
   lastLogoff: 0
   lastLogon: 0
   pwdLastSet: 131795783694428731
   primaryGroupID: 513
   objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAA3G4iEdoCV++319XAWgQAAA==
   accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
   logonCount: 0
   sAMAccountName: luser03
   sAMAccountType: 805306368
   userPrincipalName: luser03@kelamayi.com
   objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
   uidNumber: 20003
   gidNumber: 20001
   unixHomeDirectory: /home/luser03
   loginShell: /bin/bash

   # search reference
   ref: ldap://ForestDnsZones.kelamayi.com/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=kelamayi,DC=com

   # search reference
   ref: ldap://DomainDnsZones.kelamayi.com/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=kelamayi,DC=com

   # search reference
   ref: ldap://kelamayi.com/CN=Configuration,DC=kelamayi,DC=com

   # search result
   search: 2
   result: 0 Success

   # numResponses: 5
   # numEntries: 1
   # numReferences: 3
   ```

   I can also use the Java API to connect to AD with ldaps. The `getent passwd` also works well.

   ```
   $ getent passwd luser03
   luser03:*:20003:513:luser03:/home/luser03:/bin/bash
   $ getent passwd 20002
   luser02:*:20002:513:luser02:/home/luser02:/bin/bash
   $ getent passwd 20003
   luser03:*:20003:513:luser03:/home/luser03:/bin/bash
   ```
2. Linux (CentOS 6): I am going to list below attached.

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/nslcd.conf`:

   ```
   binddn CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   bindpw Passw0rd
   uid nslcd
   gid ldap
   uri ldap://114.116.43.118:389/
   base dc=kelamayi,dc=com
   ssl no
   tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
   filter passwd (objectClass=user)
   filter group  (objectClass=group)
   map     passwd uid sAMAccountName
   map     passwd  homeDirectory      unixHomeDirectory
   map     passwd  gecos              displayName
   map     passwd  gidNumber          primaryGroupID
   map     group   uniqueMember       member
   ```

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/openldap/ldap.conf`:

   ```
   base dc=kelamayi,dc=com
   uri ldap://114.116.43.118:389/
   ssl no
   tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
   pam_password md5
   ```

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/pam_ldap.conf`:

   ```
   base dc=kelamayi,dc=com
   uri ldap://114.116.43.118:389/
   ssl no
   tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
   pam_password md5
   ```

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

   ```
   auth        required      pam_env.so
   auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
   auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
   auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
   auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
   auth        required      pam_deny.so
   account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
   account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
   account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
   account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
   account     required      pam_permit.so
   password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-2 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
   password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
   password    required      pam_deny.so
   session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
   session     required      pam_limits.so
   session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
   session     required      pam_unix.so
   session     optional      pam_ldap.so
   ```

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/pam.d/password-auth`:

   ```
   auth        required      pam_env.so
   auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
   auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
   auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
   auth        required      pam_deny.so
   account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
   account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
   account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
   account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
   account     required      pam_permit.so
   password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-2 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1
   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
   password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
   password    required      pam_deny.so
   session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
   session     required      pam_limits.so
   session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
   session     required      pam_unix.so
   session     optional      pam_ldap.so
   ```

   `grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#' /etc/nsswitch`:

   ```
   passwd:     files ldap
   shadow:     files ldap
   group:      files ldap
   hosts:      files dns
   bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
   ethers:     files
   netmasks:   files
   networks:   files
   protocols:  files
   rpc:        files
   services:   files ldap
   netgroup:   files ldap
   publickey:  nisplus
   automount:  files ldap
   aliases:    files nisplus
   ```
3. Test&Debug:

   ```
   ssh -v luser03@114.116.41.255
   nslcd -d
   tail -f -n /var/log/secure
   ```

   log of ssh:

   ```
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

        here pending for a while, about 10 seconds.

   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
   debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
   debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
   debug1: Next authentication method: password
   luser03@114.116.41.255's password:
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
   Permission denied, please try again.
   luser03@114.116.41.255's password:
   ```

   debug of `nslcd`.
   I do not know why there is a "ldap_result() timed out"  in the log before input the password. (This performance issue was addressed by Stefan. Thanks him!)

   ```
   nslcd: DEBUG: add_uri(ldap://114.116.43.118:389/)
   nslcd: DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR,"/etc/openldap/cacerts")
   nslcd: version 0.7.5 starting
   nslcd: DEBUG: unlink() of /var/run/nslcd/socket failed (ignored): No such file or directory
   nslcd: DEBUG: setgroups(0,NULL) done
   nslcd: DEBUG: setgid(55) done
   nslcd: DEBUG: setuid(65) done
   nslcd: accepting connections

   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: connection from pid=2856 uid=0 gid=0
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(luser03)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=kelamayi,dc=com", filter="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=luser03))")
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://114.116.43.118:389/)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://114.116.43.118:389/")
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: rebinding to ldap://kelamayi.com/CN=Configuration,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://kelamayi.com/CN=Configuration,DC=kelamayi,DC=com")
   nslcd: [8b4567] ldap_result() timed out
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_abandon()
   nslcd: [8b4567] DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=2856 uid=0 gid=0
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(luser03)
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=kelamayi,dc=com", filter="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=luser03))")
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://114.116.43.118:389/)
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://114.116.43.118:389/")
   nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=2856 uid=0 gid=0
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(luser03)
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=kelamayi,dc=com", filter="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=luser03))")
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://114.116.43.118:389/)
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://114.116.43.118:389/")
   nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: connection from pid=2856 uid=0 gid=0
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: nslcd_passwd_byname(luser03)
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=kelamayi,dc=com", filter="(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=luser03))")
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://114.116.43.118:389/)
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=luser02,CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://114.116.43.118:389/")
   nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results
   ```

   `/var/log/secure`:

   ```
   Aug 24 19:42:07 ecs-c191-0006 sshd[2856]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure;
   logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=114.116.42.247  user=luser03
   ```

   Tried to enable pam debug by [Switch on PAM debugging to Syslog](https://serverfault.com/questions/249671/switch-on-pam-debugging-to-syslog),
   but I got another error when build:

   ```
   patching file modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_passwd.c
   Hunk #1 succeeded at 233 (offset -7 lines).
   patching file modules/pam_unix/pam_unix.8.xml
   patching file modules/pam_unix/passverify.c
   Hunk #1 succeeded at 1088 (offset -7 lines).
   patching file modules/pam_unix/passverify.h
   patching file modules/pam_unix/support.c
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 495.
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file modules/pam_unix/support.c.rej
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend testing the connection with `getent passwd` before changing the PAM configuration.

Using your configuration, I also suffered from long waiting times and occasional time outs. I think this happens because you only define `base dc=kelamayi,dc=com` as search base instead of map-specific ones.

According to [man 5 nslcd.conf](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/5/nslcd.conf/)

```
   base [MAP] DN
      Specifies the base distinguished name (DN) to use as search base.  This option  may
      be supplied multiple times and all specified bases will be searched.

      A  global  search  base may be specified or a MAP-specific one.  If no MAP-specific
      search bases are defined the global ones are used.
```

So to speed up the search and prevent time outs, you could (and probably should) define (at least) the following bases in `/etc/nslcd.conf`:

```
base passwd CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
base group  CN=unixGrp,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
base shadow CN=Users,DC=kelamayi,DC=com
```

See also: https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup for further information on setting up PAM with LDAP.

Update (2020-03-20): Having learned more about PAM and LDAP, the problem probably was that `pam_unix.so` will try to authenticate an user (via the nss facility) before `pam_ldap.so` is consulted. Order matters in a PAM configuration so `pam_ldap.so` should probably be either before `pam_unix.so` or you could use `pam_localuser.so` to skip `pam_unix.so` if a user is in `/etc/passwd`. I don't know why the nss-pam-ldapd website suggested this order. Switching to [SSSD](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd) is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your input. You are right. After I use the new BASE DN: `base ou=portal,dc=kelamayi,dc=com` which only contains the 3 users luser02,luser03 and luser04. The `getent passwd` and `getent passwd luser03` and `getent passwd 20003` 20003 is the luser03's uid.  All works and responses immediately. I updated the question with this information. But the same problem still exists.  I can share the env to you if if you are interested in the issue....

Comment: I am able to use `getent passwd`,`getent group` commands to fetch the information from AD. But `getent shadow` only returns the local ones. I think the problem may be clear now that is the shadow/password needs to be mapped for AD. But I tried to config /etc/pam_ldap.conf and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf according to [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/355701/passwd-for-ldap-users?newreg=2daaf8ff894544fca93ae987d37070be) and still not work.

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/87133 for possible mappings. I hope it helps.

Comment: Stefan, thanks for your help. I still could not make it work and finally I switched to use sssd and made it work.